# How to bulk load data in pyarrow.Table format into BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, pyarrow

As per the python API documentation of BigQuery (version 3.3.2), there is a method for `insert_rows_from_dataframe` (`dataframe: pandas.DataFrame`) but no similar method exists for PyArrow.

```
insert_rows_from_dataframe(
    table: Union[
        google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table,
        google.cloud.bigquery.table.TableReference,
        str,
    ],
    dataframe,
    selected_fields: Optional[
        Sequence[google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField]
    ] = None,
    chunk_size: int = 500,
    **kwargs: Dict
)
```

So what is an equivalent way to load data from `pyarrow.Table` format into a BigQuery table.

Answer (score 0):

This method ultimately writes a file (I believe parquet by default) and the executes a load job.  You can do that directly with the arrow table.  It might pay to file a feature request for the BQ library to support this use case directly.